# why python assign list values by reference

Tags: python, list, reference

We know this in Python

```
a= [1, 2]
b= [a, a]
print b
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
a.append(3)
print b
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

This is because `b` have reference of same list `a` and appending anthing in `a` also changes `b`.
My question is -- What is the use or advantage of this behavior?
Why Python assign list values by reference?? 
If I am doing `b =[a,a]` obusely it means I am interested in values of `a` not in what happens to `a` later on.
We can achieve this as

```
b=[a[:], a[:]] 
#or
b=[a,a]
a=[]
```

but Why this is not the default behavior in python? Why Python is designed like this!!

Comment: Because Python is pass by reference. The creator decreed.

Comment: Why Python is designed like this? Because that is how GVR has designed it!?

Comment: And the BDFL said, Let there be pass-by-reference! And lo, there was pass-by-reference. And it was good.

Comment: Pass by reference has little to do with it, since in this case nothing is being passed to anything.

Comment: `a` is the reference, that gets passed around.

Comment: "Pass by reference" usually refers to function/method arguments, but I suppose I can't argue with your logic :)

Comment: `a = [1,2,3]; b = a; b[0]` you are just passing a reference of `a` to `b` :) `b` points to the same location as `a` which points to your list

Comment: Don't know why its getting -ve vote!! Just saying Python is designed like this is not much useful. I am interested in logic behind this as I have seen some disadvantage of this but not any advantage!!

Comment: advantages? imagine that if you'd do something like func(L) it would copy the whole list, and what will happen if the list is about 100M items.

Comment: there's a brief discussion about names in the Python docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects

Answer (score 5):

In Python, Everything is an Object.
Remember this rule & you won't get confused anywhere.

In the above example, we can say that

```
b=[a,a]
```

Object of b is now a list

```
[object of a,object of a ]
```

So any modification to a is reflected here.

One interesting example to prove this is we all know tuples are immutable,
Now;

```
a=[1,2]

b=(0,a)


a.append(3)

print b # (0,[1,2,3])
```

Amazing, how did the tuple get modified here. Answer is same as above..

Comment: I accept your argument but don't you think Python should be smart enough to not modify `b` afterwards because I want to append something in `a` not in `b`

Comment: How does it know that?  It's entirely possible that when appending to `a` you would want it to edit `b`.  Python gives the flexibility to do either by using `b = (0,a)` or `b= (0,a[:])`.  Just because it's not what you're familiar with doesn't mean it's not a valid way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

> If I am doing b =[a,a] obusely it means I am interested in values of a not in what happens to a later on.

I don't see why that's obvious at all. A list is just a way of holding things. I might be interested in the values of the things, but just as likely I'm interested in the things themselves - I want to pass them to a function that mutates them, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Python assigns *everything* by reference. The `=` operator simply binds the name on the left side to the object on the right side. This only becomes obvious to most people when mutable objects are used on the right side, and then mutated by calling instance methods like `.append()`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's a language design choice. It simplifies the semantics of Python to say that [Python has names not variables](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables). This way, the semantics of `=` are very simple: the LHS is simply a new name to refer to the RHS.